# php+oracle, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, sql, oracle

im have error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/daily.php on line 49. All tags closed and line 49 not exist!   What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<span class="noprint">
<form action="daily.php" method="post">
 <p>time: <input type="text" name="date" value="01.02.2017" pattern="[0-3][0-9].[0-1][0-9].20[0-5][0-9]"/><input type="submit" /><input type="button" value="print" oncli$
</form>
</span>
</body>

<?php
require 'connect.php';
oci_execute($stid);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT HK_GOSP.*,  KARD.FIO,  HK_FULL.DIAG,  HK_FULL.GK,  HK_FULL.EXTRA,  HK_FULL.REZ,  HK_FULL.PROBA,  HK_FULL.REAG,  HK_FULL.EF,  HK_FULL.PPK1,  HK_FULL.PPK2,  HK_FULL.PERELIV,  HK_FULL.PPK3,  HK_FULL.REM,  HK_FULL.SGBN, HK_FULL.NPPYEAR AS NPPYEAR1 FROM HK_GOSP,  KARD,  HK_FULL WHERE HK_GOSP.DG LIKE '%" . $_POST['date']  ."%' ");
oci_execute($stid);
?>
<table border='1'>
    <?php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach ($row as $item) {
            echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";
       echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure if the parser is barking at you with UEOF it's gonna be a missing tag or failure to close a loop or something like that. I see one possibility, at least.

Comment: '}' missing before `echo "</tr>\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missing a closing bracket:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;")."</td>\n";      
    } // This one here
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```